# reading images from a directory while copying images into the same directory

Tags: c

I need to do such works just like the title means.I need to check continuously where there are pictures under a specified directory,and read them to do some necessarily process. But the same time  someone else may copy images into the same directory. What should I do to avoid reading incomplete images?
Thanks very much.
I'm using C.But any language is OK. I just need an idea.
I'm wondering if it's possible to judge whether it's a complete image?

Comment: Perhaps examine the file modification timestamp (`st_mtime` member in `struct stat`), and postpone processing files if they have been modified only a few seconds ago? Something like five seconds should work well, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, friend. But it's not a good way if I need to process many images. I got a better solution, copying images to the directory and then create any_type_empty_files has the same names with the images, and reading images only after have checked these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Linux, there are the guarantee that moving a file in the same device is an atomic operation. That means that either the file doesn't exist, or the file is complete.
More info in the [man of rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) : look at the "EXDEV" error.

If you can't make this, I advise to create a special dir in your target dir (nommed "tmp" ?), copying into the special dir and after move thie file from the special dir to the target dir.

Under Windows, I think there is the same guarantee, but I'm not really sure.